# WWW in urls and user session in browsers

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, web, dns

One of our web application has been deployed to godaddy server recently. We have provided with a domain name like http://sampleurl.com. Now we are able to fetch the site through http://sampleurl.com as well as http://www.sampleurl.com.

My doubts are:

1. why is it not necessary to specify WWW in url? (But some browsers adds WWW to the url with domain name)
2. Now a serious problem. In a browser two different tabs loaded with same web site. In first tab url specified with www and in other tab www has been ommited from url. And I found browsers considers this as two different web sites and there fore keeps two different sessions.
3. To solve this problem we have come with a solution to redirect the page url to www if it is not specified, so that we can mainitain same user session across tabs. Is that a good practise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Browser will never append `www.` to the URL on its own. It's a webserver of a webpage that is configured in a way that redirect you to `www.domain.com` if you're trying to visit `domain.com`.
2. `www.domain.com` is another subdomain, just like `my-subdomain.domain.com` is. That means it's considered by browsers as different website. It's also quite important that bots of search engines consider those two *separate* websites, as... separate.
3. Yes, it's a very good practice to redirect from `www.domain.com` to `domain.com` (`www.` "prefix" is completly redundand).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is good practice to map/redirect the naked domain (sample.com) to the www subdomain (www.sample.com).

Like you mentioned these are two different websites.